# When using TabIndex, do numbers follow a logical order?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

When using the tab index in asp.net, If i were to use a series of tab indices, is it possible to establish a hierarchy so that i can access things in order as a keyboard user?

for example, if I set all my tabs to index 0, and then set the first element inside those tabs to index 1, will that recognize it as an index order?